# How do I scrape Twitter usernames using Selenium properly?

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

So, I'm trying to scrape Twitter followers but the issue is, it scrapes unnecessary links too that are not profile pages (Twitter accs).

What the below code does is, open the Twitter account page that you want to scrape followers from, and gets links of profile pages using locate element by xpath, while gradually scrolling down to get all the present followers.

Here's my code:

```
def extract_followers_func():
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/Username/followers")
    sleep(5)
    for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
        file = open("scrapedlist.txt", "a")
        file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
    sleep(5)
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait to load page
        sleep(5)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
            file = open("scrapedlist.txt", "a")
            file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
```

What would be a more effective way to do this? I want just the usernames, not every unnecessary link.

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import threading

import time

from time import sleep

import datetime

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

root = tk.Tk()

app_width = 300
app_height = 320

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

#
ser = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

testbtn_txt = tk.StringVar()
testbtn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=testbtn_txt, command=lambda:extract_followers_func(), font="Arial", bg="#808080", fg="white", height=1, width=10)
testbtn_txt.set("Test")
testbtn.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5)


def extract_followers_func():
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/Username/followers")
    sleep(5)
    for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link" and not(@aria-hidden) and not(contains(@href,'search')) and not(contains(@href,'Live')) and not(@rel)]'):
        file = open("scrapedlist.txt", "a")
        file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
    sleep(5)
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait to load page
        sleep(5)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link" and not(@aria-hidden) and not(contains(@href,'search')) and not(contains(@href,'Live')) and not(@rel)]'):
            file = open("scrapedlist.txt", "a")
            file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!
You just need to finetune the locator.
So, instead of

```py
'//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'
```

You should use

```py
'//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link" and not(@aria-hidden) and not(contains(@href,"search")) and not(contains(@href,"Live")) and not(@rel)]'
```

Comment: Nothing changed except it doesn't show every scrapped line twice like before... I still see unnecessary links.

Comment: Should I provide you with full code?

Comment: I have answered according to what I see on my twitter followers page. In case the updated answer (updated just now) still gives you irrelevant links I'd like to get your credentials to see what actually happens on your account followers page.

Comment: I get links like these: 

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23nftart&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23nftcommunity&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23NFTDrop&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23FeaturedNFT&src=hashtag_click

Comment: OK, but I don't have such elements on my twitter followers page. So in order to give you a correct locator I need to see page containing such elements to create a correct locator

Comment: https://twitter.com/cryptoknight567/followers

Comment: OK, please see the updated locator

Comment: 1. "(" was not closed
2. Expected ":"

Two errors after I edited the code.

Comment: What was not closed, where? What was expected, where?

Comment: This is what Python said in errors.

Comment: This line: //div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link" and not(@aria-hidden) and not(contains(@href,'search')) and not(contains(@href,'Live')) and not(@rel)]

Comment: OK, where exactly what was wrong?

Comment: When I replaced the code with your latest code then it showed those errors.

Comment: I still can't see what is wrong with my expression...

Comment: Check my post. I provided full code.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. I mixed single `'` with double `"`. You copied it as is so you have problems... Now I fixed that